# Relation between the Hessian and Laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M^{n},g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold of smooth boundary $\partial M$. Assume that Ricci curvature of $M$ is $Ric^{M}\geq0$, 
and the second fund. form of  $\partial M$ is $II\geq c>0$.
Suppose that $(\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu})\mid_{\partial M}=0$. Is the following inequality is true $$|Hess(u)|^{2}\leq (\Delta u)^{2}$$
If yes, how I can prove it. Thank you in advance

(Noting that by using Bochner formula we know that $\int_{M}\bigl((\Delta u)^{2}-|Hess(u)|^{2}\bigr)dv_{g}\geq0$).

Comment: I need an answer please to progress.

Comment: I would like to know of the question is blocked. Thank you

Comment: I don't know much of the geometrical background, but it seems to me that the inequality is trivially false. Just take $\mathbb R^n$. The term $|\text{Hess} (u)|^2$ contains all derivatives, the term $(\Delta u)^2$ only contains the $\partial_x^2, \partial_y^2, \partial_z^2\ldots$ derivatives. The obvious inequality is $(\Delta u)^2\le |\text{Hess}(u)|^2$. This said, *unless* you mean something different for $|\cdot|$ (I recognize it as a matrix norm) OR $u$ solves an elliptic equation.

Comment: this inequality is false in general, but  you have to note that $u$ is not any function, it satisfies some conditions

Comment: As Giuseppe wrote, a boundary condition alone is nowhere near enough to get a pointwise inequality. You can easily construct a counterexample on *any* $M$ by choosing a function that is saddle-shaped at some point in the interior and has compact support disjoint from $\partial M$.